# Style to picture item in repeater

Tags: css, image, binary, styles

Is it possible to change size and width for this image when I display it?
As it stored as picture and I can't change it to hyperlink and use the img tag.

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding: 0px;">
   <%# ((SPListItem)Container.DataItem)["Rollup Image"] %>
</div>
```